# Get different result when do same command in console and exec()

Tags: php, console, exec, ocr

When I do in console `/home/..myserver_path../.local/bin/gocr -i '/home/..myserver_path../runtime//tmp/135_45_ca4b78115a191517c9e356d34deb000c.jpg' 2>&1` it work ok.

But when I do in php script

```
exec("/home/..myserver_path../.local/bin/gocr -i '/home/..myserver_path../runtime//tmp/135_45_ca4b78115a191517c9e356d34deb000c.jpg' 2>&1", $out);
```

I get errors:

sh: 1: djpeg: not found

ERROR pnm.c L328: unexpected EOF

Which difference in this ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP code is syntactically invalid. You need to escape the single quotes used in the command.

Edit: After the syntax corrections, I would take a guess that djpeg is missing from your path for PHP but is on path in your shell. What do you get when you run `which djpeg` from your shell?

Edit: As per the discussion below, it looks like this is the case. To solve this please try this PHP code:

```
exec("export PATH=\$PATH:/home/..myserver_path../.local/bin/; /home/..myserver_path../.local/bin/gocr -i '/home/..myserver_path../runtime//tmp/135_45_ca4b78115a191517c9e356d34deb000c.jpg' 2>&1", $out);
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited it to make more understandable, originally it is: exec('/home/..myserver_path../.local/bin/gocr -i ' . escapeshellarg(Yii::getAlias('@runtime//tmp/'.$pieceFilename)) . ' 2>&1', $out);

Comment: I got nothing when run 'which djpeg'. How I may add it to my php path? Its on shared hosting

Comment: Just to be clear, you are running the command on the same server that is running PHP right? And it works in the console but not in a PHP script?

Comment: Because if it's not the same server then that is the difference. You are missing the djpeg dependency on your PHP server.

Comment: Yes, its same server. Tried set_include_path(), no result

Comment: Are you using SSH to access your server to try the commands on?

Comment: I don't really see how `which djpeg` could be returning nothing, but your command could still work. djpeg is a requirement of gocr (with JPEG input) so if it's not installed then the command shouldn't work at all.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought you asking what return 'which djpeg' if I call it from php. If call it just in shell I get '/home/..my_path../.local/bin/djpeg'

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer with the PHP code to add djpeg to your path. Please try that.